# In Ruby, using net-ping, why does Net::Ping::TCP.new('stackoverflow.com').ping? return false?

Tags: ruby

### Using:

- **Ruby** *2.1.0*
- **net-ping** *1.7.2*

### irb

```
> require 'net/ping'
> Net::Ping::TCP.new('stackoverflow.com').ping?
=> false
```

Why isn't this returning `true`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to pass `http` as the second paramter as shown in the [example](https://github.com/djberg96/net-ping/blob/master/examples/example_pingtcp.rb)
:

```
p  Net::Ping::TCP.new('stackoverflow.com','http').ping? # true
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer @fmendez.  Do you know what the second parameter does?  Is it just telling `.new()` to use HTTP Port 80?  I'm having trouble finding the answer in the docs.

Comment: @franksort That is correct. If you look at this class: https://github.com/djberg96/net-ping/blob/master/lib/net/ping/tcp.rb  the `#ping` implementation is using the `Socket#getaddrinfo` which, as part of its parameters, takes the protocol (`http` in this case).

Comment: @franksort In the `API` they choose the unfortunate/poor name of `port` for it, so that value is traveling in the `port` parameter.